# Identifier for win64 configuration in Qmake

Tags: windows, qt, 64-bit, qt4, qmake

Is there a "win64" identifier in Qmake project files? [Qt Qmake advanced](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qmake-advanced-usage.html) documentation does not mention other than unix / macx / win32.

So far I've tried using:

```
win32:message("using win32")
win64:message("using win64")
amd64:message("using amd64")
```

The result is always "using win32".

Must I use a separate project-file for x32 and x64 projects, so they would compile against correct libraries? Is there any other way to identify between 32-bit and 64-bit environments?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I do it like this

```
win32 {

    ## Windows common build here

    !contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch, x86_64) {
        message("x86 build")

        ## Windows x86 (32bit) specific build here

    } else {
        message("x86_64 build")

        ## Windows x64 (64bit) specific build here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Since Qt5 you can use `QT_ARCH` to detect whether your configuration is 32 or 64. When the target is 32-bit, that returns `i386` and in case of a 64-bit target it has the value of `x86_64`. So it can be used like:

```
contains(QT_ARCH, i386) {
    message("32-bit")
} else {
    message("64-bit")
}
```

Answer (score 12):

UPDATE: since very recently, Qt has a way of doing this transparently and easily, without manual hassle:

```
win32-g++:contains(QMAKE_HOST.arch, x86_64):{
    do something
}
```

Source: [the brand new Qt Dev FAQ](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_detect_in_the_.pro_file_if_i_am_compiling_for_a_32_bit_or_a_64_bi)

Comment: Wow, I've been searching this for days. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be QMAKE_TARGET instead of QMAKE_HOST?

Comment: @Simon [`QMAKE_TARGET`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-target) contains the name of the project target (i.e. the binary file). `qmake` wasn't ever designed to handle cross-compilation where target != host.

Comment: @rubenvb `qmake` can cross-compile, e.g. for Windows on Linux. Accepted answer uses `QMAKE_TARGET` but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Simon those are patched Qt sources, and mkspecs, that allow that. So no, qmake (unmodified) does not allow cross-compilation. It's a single-qmake-and-Qt-per-target thing. I don't know if Qt5 changed anything for the better. Just follow the link, QMAKE_TARGET is not what you and the OP think it is. At least if I can believe the documentation...

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out one way to do it.

Qt allows you to pass arbitrary config parameters which you can use to separate the targets.

By having a conditional config in your project file:

```
CONFIG(myX64, myX64|myX32) {
    LIBPATH += C:\Coding\MSSDK60A\Lib\x64
} else {
    LIBPATH += C:\Coding\MSSDK60A\Lib
}
```

and passing that custom config to `qmake` with

```
qmake CONFIG+=myX64
```

you get the wanted result.

Comment: Of course you can use different .pro files that include the common parts too, but personally I find that a pain in the...

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create and use a new mkspec, I think qmake also defines a platform identifier named after the current mkspec.  Why do you need to test for 64 bit?

Reed

Comment: I want to use Win32 API in Qt and I must link against libraries from Windows SDK. Obviously those libraries are in different directories, and thus I need to include different files using LIBS. Maybe I'm doing it all wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Specifically in Qt Open Source Edition, not commercial Qt with VS integration, but from the command line and via qmake project files.