# Qt linker Error on HWND, HDC

Tags: winapi, qt, gdi

I have included `windows.h`. Its even working well and fine if I just comment out `HWND`, `HDC`, `HBITMAP`, `GetBitmapBits()` etc.. I think I need to include the proper LIB ?? what LIB to include ? Is it `-lgdi32` ??

**Error Message:** :: `error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

EDIT
after adding `LIBS += -lgdi32` there was no linker Error and It compiled Successfully. So Its solved I think !!!! or Is it ?

Comment: Your question should include the error message at least.

Comment: Well I thought This is an well known Problem. I've added the Error Message. Check Edit Please

Comment: Instead of editing the solution into your question, you should probably add that as an answer to your question instead.  You are allowed to accept your own answers, especially since you fixed your own problem.  Also, the error message you put in the question is very vague; all that says is that there *was* an error, not what the error was.  See my answer below for an example of what @Friend-Pal was asking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this was the only error message compiler fired. What can I do if compiler fires a `very vague` Error Message ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you have a solution in an edit to your question, I think it might be useful to illustrate how you can fix these sorts of problems in the future.

When the linker gives an error, that likely means that you are trying to reference a piece of executable code that it can't find.  There should have been a series of errors above the line you quoted that state which specific functions were causing the problem, such as:

> foo.obj: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetBitmapBits@12 referenced in function...

Output may be slightly different for your particular linker.  It will probably include the phrase "unresolved external".  Those errors are what @Friend-Pal was actually asking for.

When you get an unresolved external reference, you fix it by linking in the appropriate library.  To determine which library to include for which function, look at the documentation.  For example, the documentation for [GetBitmapBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states at the bottom:

> Minimum supported client: Windows 2000 Professional
>   Minimum supported server: Windows 2000 Server
>   Header: Wingdi.h (include Windows.h)
>   **Library: Gdi32.lib**
>   DLL: Gdi32.dll

The method of adding the library reference depends on the specific linker you are using.  In your case, based on the edit to your question, that should be `-lgdi32` to link in the `gdi32.lib` library.

Repeat this process until all the references are resolved.

Data types (`HWND`, `HDC`, `HBITMAP`, etc.) only need the appropriate header file; they do not have any actual executable code associated with them, so they don't affect the linker.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why compiler didn't fire a Single unresolved reference error. then I made a wild guess thinking windows.h functions might cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Tadmas about looking up MSDN to see which library you require, when using Qt you can define the libraries without making changes to the linker flags, etc.

- If you are using Microsoft's compiler, adding e.g `LIBS += Gdi32.lib` line to the `.pro` file would be sufficient. Done!
- If you are using GCC, you should supply the full path to the lib file, e.g `LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/Gdi32.lib"`.
- If you have a project that targets both 32-bit and 64-bit GCC builds (and you have built Qt with a 64-bit GCC on Windows), you should use conditional scopes in the .pro file to [determine if you are building for 32-bit or 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356666/identifier-for-win64-configuration-in-qmake) and supply the path to the 64-bit lib file in 64-bit builds. e.g:

  ```
  win32-g++:!contains(QMAKE_HOST.arch, x86_64) {
      LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/Gdi32.lib"
  } else {
      LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/x64/Gdi32.lib"
  }
  ```