# Qt Creator: how to tell win32 from win64

Tags: c++, qt, 64-bit, qmake

I have to do something like this in a .pro file:

```
win32 {
    LIBS += -L../3rdparty/libusb-win32/lib/msvc -llibusb
} else
win64 {
    LIBS += -L../3rdparty/libusb-win32/lib/msvc_x64 -llibusb
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work, it always links win32 library.
Any suggestions?

Comment: why the else? doesn't it work without else? are you compiling in x64 platform correctly?

Comment: I guess "else" doesn't make any difference. And no, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifier for win64 configuration in Qmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356666/identifier-for-win64-configuration-in-qmake)

Comment: rubenvb: thanks a lot, didn't find it for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `QT_ARCH` variable to detect whether your configuration is 32 or 64 :

```
contains(QT_ARCH, i386) {
    message("32-bit")
}else {
    message("64-bit")
}
```

When the target is 32-bit, the variable returns `i386` and in case of a 64-bit target it has the value of `x86_64`.

Comment: Neat! Not formally the same as detecting the compiler architecture, but effectively the same because you'll have trouble building a project that uses 32-bit Qt with 64-bit compiler and vice versa.

Comment: Note: this seems to "detect" what you set under the "Qt version" field of the Kit Config.  If you set your 32-bit mingw-w64 kit to use 64-bit QT then this code will detect 64-bit.   (Why would someone do that? In my use case I'm using Qt Creator to build a non-QT project , since I like the IDE; and I haven't installed 32-bit QT,  and so you have to choose 64-bit QT since there are no other viable options).

Answer (score 9):

October 2016 update. The following code works on Windows (at least with all the recent MSVC compilers - didn't test MinGW), Mac OS X (clang) and Linux (GCC). Feel free to omit the first clause and refer to `QT_ARCH` directly if you don't need Qt 4 support.

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
    TARGET_ARCH=$${QT_ARCH}
} else {
    TARGET_ARCH=$${QMAKE_HOST.arch}
}

contains(TARGET_ARCH, x86_64) {
    ARCHITECTURE = x64
} else {
    ARCHITECTURE = x86
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how we do that:

```
win32 {
win32-g++:contains(QMAKE_HOST.arch, x86_64):{
    LIBS += ... #for win64
} else {
    LIBS += ... #for win32
}
}
```

Comment: This is for Qt 4 only. For Qt 5, see my answer.